# Interpreted Languages For Mobile Platforms

Tags: windows-mobile, mobile, palm-os, interpreted-language

I'm starting this *community wiki* to get all the interpreted languages that can be embedded, but let's begin:

- Windows CE

  - [Perl](http://www.rainer-keuchel.de/wince/perlce.html)
  - [Ruby](http://readlist.com/lists/ruby-lang.org/ruby-talk/13/65913.html)
  - [Python](http://pythonce.sourceforge.net/)
- Palm OS

  - [Python](http://pippy.sourceforge.net/)
- iPod

  - [Python](http://ciberjacobo.com/python-ipod)

Now if I missed some language, please post and remember to put the link. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Actually Ruby is said to be possible on iPhone, Blackberry, Windows Mobile and Symbian/Android ( soon ) by [Rhodes](http://www.infoq.com/news/2008/12/rhodes-iphone-winmobile-rim)

Answer (score 1):

You can also get python for PSP, if that's the sort of thing you're looking for.

Java might be the most ported, it's on a whole bunch of mobile platforms (but that's way on the outer edge of interpreted), I have heard that Python is ported to more platforms than Java, but I can't verify that.

[List of python on other platforms](http://www.python.org/download/other/)

Python for PSP seems to no longer exist. Their website is down.

Comment: Hmm.. I went to look for the website, and it seems no longer to exist, shame, it was a pretty nice platform. I did come across a list of python on other platforms though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Python for S60](http://opensource.nokia.com/projects/pythonfors60/). Please could you share this wiki?